# android java using HPRT printer with ZPLPrinterHelper not working correctly when print UTF-8 character

Tags: java, thermal-printer, zpl

I'm currently working with SDK on java to connect with HPRT Prime but I cannot print UTF-8 charactor. Already try to search document but it always give me something else or it use the command code
there is no specific explanation in the pdf file about how to set encode language with ^CI command.
some work but some doesn't.

```
        zplPrinterHelper =  ZPLPrinterHelper.getZPL(thisCon);


    zplPrinterHelper.start();
//    zplPrinterHelper.LanguageEncode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    zplPrinterHelper.printData("^XA^CWZ,E:SOU000.TTF^FS^XZ \n" +
            "^XA \n" +
            "^CI28 \n" +
            "^FO110,150^AZN,50,50^FD a á ă ả ạ. ê ế é ể ệ ẹ. o ơ ở ò ờ ọ ợ ộ ổ . ^FS \n" +

            "^PQ1 \n" +
            "^XZ");
```

the result on internet all about using ZPL command and come from Zebra devices.
the imgae below is the result when I print

[image]

Comment: yeah. Im texting to them already for a day but still not work, I dowload font that support vietnamese, try to use ZPL command code but nothing show up. It is perfectly okay if just print out latin character.
My code base on their apk demo so dont  have any clue now

Comment: Im trying in another way is pass image from flutter to java. but get stuck when covert type. it need byte[] in java then I still dont find the correct type from flutter to pass it